# cannot copy file from windows to ubuntu

Tags: copy, paste

i'm using windows and Ubuntu OS in same machine.i cant copy files or folders between two partitions created using Ubuntu and windows.how to resolve this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achive this under linux first you should mount windows partitions into your filesystem.
You can check by writing in your console: df you can check filesystems mounted on your box. There is also a graphical tool (Disks) which can help you check what partitions are mounted, and mount adidiotnal partitions. Please provide more detail if you still have problems.
Under windows there is a lot of third party software to access linux partitions.

Comment: Also, if there is no common data partition, make sure you actually shut down Windows, else the partition won't mount.